How to apply Grad-CAM on my custom Model in Pytorch?
I have this model for brain tumor detection project.
I want to add Grad-Cam, but Most of implantations are in TensorFlow and the ones that are in Pytorch are in known models not customs.
I want to apply it on my trained custom model.
Here's my model:
# Define Architecture For CNN_TUMOR Model
class CNN_TUMOR(nn.Module):

    # Network Initialisation
    def __init__(self, params):

        super(CNN_TUMOR, self).__init__()

        Cin,Hin,Win = params["shape_in"]
        init_f = params["initial_filters"]
        num_fc1 = params["num_fc1"]
        num_classes = params["num_classes"]
        self.dropout_rate = params["dropout_rate"]

        # Convolution Layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(Cin, init_f, kernel_size=3)
        h,w=findConv2dOutShape(Hin,Win,self.conv1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(init_f, 2*init_f, kernel_size=3)
        h,w=findConv2dOutShape(h,w,self.conv2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(2*init_f, 4*init_f, kernel_size=3)
        h,w=findConv2dOutShape(h,w,self.conv3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(4*init_f, 8*init_f, kernel_size=3)
        h,w=findConv2dOutShape(h,w,self.conv4)

        # compute the flatten size
        self.num_flatten=h*w*8*init_f
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.num_flatten, num_fc1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(num_fc1, num_classes)

    def forward(self,X):

        # Convolution & Pool Layers
        X = F.relu(self.conv1(X));
        X = F.max_pool2d(X, 2, 2)
        X = F.relu(self.conv2(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X, 2, 2)
        X = F.relu(self.conv3(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X, 2, 2)
        X = F.relu(self.conv4(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X, 2, 2)
        X = X.view(-1, self.num_flatten)
        X = F.relu(self.fc1(X))
        X = F.dropout(X, self.dropout_rate)
        X = self.fc2(X)
        return F.log_softmax(X, dim=1)

params_model={
        "shape_in": (3,256,256),
        "initial_filters": 8,
        "num_fc1": 100,
        "dropout_rate": 0.25,
        "num_classes": 2}

loss_func = nn.NLLLoss(reduction="sum")

opt = optim.Adam(cnn_model.parameters(), lr=3e-4)
lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(opt, mode='min',factor=0.5, patience=20,verbose=1)

And the rest of the code
# Function to get the learning rate
def get_lr(opt):
    for param_group in opt.param_groups:
        return param_group['lr']

# Function to compute the loss value per batch of data
def loss_batch(loss_func, output, target, opt=None):

    loss = loss_func(output, target) # get loss
    pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True) # Get Output Class
    metric_b=pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item() # get performance metric

    if opt is not None:
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()

    return loss.item(), metric_b

# Compute the loss value & performance metric for the entire dataset (epoch)
def loss_epoch(model,loss_func,dataset_dl,opt=None):

    run_loss=0.0
    t_metric=0.0
    len_data=len(dataset_dl.dataset)

    # internal loop over dataset
    for xb, yb in dataset_dl:
        # move batch to device
        xb=xb.to(device)
        yb=yb.to(device)
        output=model(xb) # get model output
        loss_b,metric_b=loss_batch(loss_func, output, yb, opt) # get loss per batch
        run_loss+=loss_b        # update running loss

        if metric_b is not None: # update running metric
            t_metric+=metric_b

    loss=run_loss/float(len_data)  # average loss value
    metric=t_metric/float(len_data) # average metric value

    return loss, metric

def Train_Val(model, params,verbose=False):

    # Get the parameters
    epochs=params["epochs"]
    loss_func=params["f_loss"]
    opt=params["optimiser"]
    train_dl=params["train"]
    val_dl=params["val"]
    lr_scheduler=params["lr_change"]
    weight_path=params["weight_path"]

    # history of loss values in each epoch
    loss_history={"train": [],"val": []}
    # histroy of metric values in each epoch
    metric_history={"train": [],"val": []}
    # a deep copy of weights for the best performing model
    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    # initialize best loss to a large value
    best_loss=float('inf')

# Train Model n_epochs (the progress of training by printing the epoch number and the associated learning rate. It can be helpful for debugging, monitoring the learning rate schedule, or gaining insights into the training process.)

    for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs)):

        # Get the Learning Rate
        current_lr=get_lr(opt)
        if(verbose):
            print('Epoch {}/{}, current lr={}'.format(epoch, epochs - 1, current_lr))


# Train Model Process


        model.train()
        train_loss, train_metric = loss_epoch(model,loss_func,train_dl,opt)

        # collect losses
        loss_history["train"].append(train_loss)
        metric_history["train"].append(train_metric)


# Evaluate Model Process


        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            val_loss, val_metric = loss_epoch(model,loss_func,val_dl)

        # store best model
        if(val_loss < best_loss):
            best_loss = val_loss
            best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

            # store weights into a local file
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), weight_path)
            if(verbose):
                print("Copied best model weights!")

        # collect loss and metric for validation dataset
        loss_history["val"].append(val_loss)
        metric_history["val"].append(val_metric)

        # learning rate schedule
        lr_scheduler.step(val_loss)
        if current_lr != get_lr(opt):
            if(verbose):
                print("Loading best model weights!")
            model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)

        if(verbose):
            print(f"train loss: {train_loss:.6f}, dev loss: {val_loss:.6f}, accuracy: {100*val_metric:.2f}")
            print("-"*10)

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)

    return model, loss_history, metric_history

That's my code, I want to implant Grad-Cam.
I'd be more than happy if you guide me.

What have you tried so far? There are at least two largely used libraries for PyTorch, did you look into it?

I haven't tried anything yet I've found this solution and this article

That's a good start, you should try it out and report here if you encounter a specific problem. Currently, your question is too broad.

The problem is the article is using VGG model and I'm using a custom one so I get confused to apply it on my model.

Have you looked at this repo?

Thanks, Ivan. I've found this helpful. in a part of this repo:
`model = resnet50(pretrained=True)
target_layers = [model.layer4[-1]]
input_tensor = # Create an input tensor image for your model..
Note: input_tensor can be a batch tensor with several images!`
I'm not sure how and what layer of my model should be the target.
I know the last layers are more suitable for this cause.

The targets seem to be the location where you want to inspect the gradcam. And in a torchvision resnet50,  layer4[-1] corresponds to the last block of layer n°4. In your case, you may try target_layers = [self.conv4] and see what you come up with.

I used this target_layers = [model.conv4] but later on here grayscale_cams = cam(input_tensor=input_tensor, targets=targets) I got an error that says: "RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 12544]' is invalid for input of size 9216". It has something to do with shapes but I couldn't figure it out. My Code
